# Where are the example programs of stm32 located in CubeIDE?

Tags: tcp, udp, stm32, ethernet, transport-layer-protocol

so my project lead told me get the ethernet understood and working on my stm32 board, I have read documents for the tcp and udp programming but they don't show any code, rather they point me to example programs that in a file location in cubeIDE. But I can't seem to locate thee example programs files. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

The sample code does not come as part of CubeIDE itself. But CubeIDE can download them from the Internet for you and make sample projects for them.

In CubeIDE, click `File -> New -> STM32 Project`

One of the tabs at the top of the window that will appear is "Example Selector". You can filter for your board / peripheral / etc.

You can then create a project and the source code for the example will be in it.